# Bash check netcat version from script

Tags: bash, netcat

Is there an easy way to check which version of netcat is used / installed? I need different execution strings for both GNU and OpenBSD versions.

Comment: You can try with feature detection. Find something that's unique to GNU version and something that's unique to BSD version, then test it.